# Emulate Zebra printer

Tags: windows, emulation, zebra-printers, zpl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print preview ZPL II commands using .NET WinForm before sending it to Zebra printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412242/print-preview-zpl-ii-commands-using-net-winform-before-sending-it-to-zebra-prin)

I am working on a Java app that prints tickets to a Zebra printer.

The problem is that I am working remotely and don't have access to the Zebra printer (or any other printer actually).

I would like to know if there is a way to emulate the Zebra printer so that I can visualize the result of the print jobs generated by my app (to PDF, bitmap image etc.).

As I understand (I am fairly new to this) Zebra printers use ZPL commands.

Is there any software printer emulator for Windows (7) that accepts ZPL commands and outputs PDF/bitmap/... ?

Comment: try http://labelary.com/viewer.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33066790/2555999 Emulate on Mac, Linux, Windows

Comment: You can also try this project https://github.com/BinaryKits/BinaryKits.Zpl

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at [ZPLViewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zplviewer/) - it works relatively well for rendering simple ZPL code but seems to fail on anything complex.

Best bet is just to purchase a printer. You can get a ZP-450 for $200. Get one with Ethernet ($100 more) and you can use the printer admin page to upload ZPL and render on-screen so you don't have to spew labels.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a link to software that Zebra created: [ZebraDesigner](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/zebralink/zebra-designer.html). It does not actually **visualize** ZPL or take ZPL as input. But it can help you design your ticket and then export it to ZPL for further processing.

Comment: This is a must-have software if you want to do EPL/ZPL design.

Comment: But it never helps to preview a zpl code.

Comment: I always had to review the ZPL to make it do exactly what I want. I believe in using a tool to make it close, then make it right myself.

Comment: @yadab print to file from ZebraDesigner and open it by notepad.

Comment: I just tried this and was utterly disappointed. ZebraDesigner issues coded ^GF fields for the most useful commands (barcode definitions, text fields). That means you can't effectively edit that information or create templates from them. I recommend Labelary.com instead.

Comment: Not available for linux, apparently...

Answer (score 2):

I wrote https://github.com/dpavlin/Printer-Zebra a few days ago which **converts ZPL `~DG` (download graphics) commands and converts it back to PBM image file**.

This is not full ZPL interpreter (since it only implements one command :-) but does work for cups generated ZPL files which is handy to find out if your printer output includes anti-aliased barcodes which are always bad...