# How to emulate zebra bluetooth printer

Tags: emulation, zebra-printers

I am developing an android app using cordova, the functionality of this app is to create invoice and later print it in zebra printer . But as I am working on a remote project and I do not have any zebra printer . Is there any way I can emulate zebra printer . I am using  ubuntu . 
I have also seen the following SO question , but those didn't help me in my scenario .

[Emulate Zebra printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540468/emulate-zebra-printer)

[Emulate ZPL printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066789/emulate-zpl-printer)