# Converting ZPL print stream into a PDF file

Tags: pdf, zpl

Is it possible to convert a ZPL print stream into a PDF file? If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 15):

You can use the Labelary [web service](http://labelary.com/service.html). Normally it would give you a PNG image:

```
wget "http://api.labelary.com/v1/printers/8dpmm/labels/4x6/0/^xa^cfa,50^fo100,100^fdHello World^fs^xz" -O label.png
```

But it will give you a PDF file if you send the right `Accept` header:

```
wget "http://api.labelary.com/v1/printers/8dpmm/labels/4x6/0/^xa^cfa,50^fo100,100^fdHello World^fs^xz" --header="Accept: application/pdf" -O label.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do it is to save the ZPL preview as an image and then convert the image to a pdf.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412242/print-preview-zpl-ii-commands-using-net-winform-before-sending-it-to-zebra-prin/7416035#7416035) for reference.