How can I create a PHP program that converts ZPL to PDF without using external services like Labelary?
I'm trying to create a PHP program that can convert ZPL (Zebra Programming Language) to PDF. However, I haven't found much information on how to do this directly in PHP. Most of the resources I've come across point me to services like Labelary.
Since services like Labelary can render ZPL, I believe it's possible, but I'm curious about how they are doing it. I wonder if it's a custom implementation or if they're using some specific libraries. Could someone provide some guidance on how to approach this? What would be the first steps? And how long would it take to build this from scratch?
And if not in PHP, in what other language is it possible?
I did some research and found that I need to first parse the ZPL so the PHP application can understand all the ZPL commands for drawing the label. And it also seems like the ZPL needs to be converted into an image first before it can be turned into a PDF. But I’m not sure if I'm correct on this or if there's a better method to handle ZPL in PHP, or perhaps in another language. So far, I haven’t found any specific libraries or tools to implement this directly.

"It seems like the ZPL needs to be converted into an image first before it can be turned into a PDF." Not necessarily.

@Olivier Could you explain please?

I think Labelary have written their own software, which, by the way, you can get a license to. As far as I know there isn't anything publicly, and freely, available that will do this for you. You could also write something yourself. ZPL is very basic and PDF is well documented. It will take time though.

You can parse the ZPL and use a PDF generating library to produce the PDF. You don't need to generate an image for that.

@KIKOSoftware How would you recommend starting with parsing ZPL? Are there any libraries or tools that could help with interpreting the ZPL commands, or would I have to build a parser from scratch?
In terms of converting ZPL to an image, is there a specific method or tool in PHP (like GD or Imagick) that you think would work best for rendering the ZPL? Or would it be better to write a custom renderer for ZPL drawing commands?

@Olivier Interesting.. Some answers on Google told me that it first needs to be saved as an image, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20502474/20262133.
ChatGPT told me the same thing, although I'm aware that might not be 100% reliable.

As I said, ZPL is very basic, and easy to parse. You could use an image as an intermediary, but it would make more sense to re-encode the ZPL source directly into PDF (= Postscript) code. Seeing that you're asking all these question about libraries and tools, it doesn't seem like you want to go down this route. It's a lot of work.

"And if not in PHP, in what other language is it possible?" Python: https://github.com/miikanissi/zebrafy

@Olivier One more reason to have a look at Python.  Ah, looked at it and it only handles the ^GF ZPL command.

Which ZPL commands do you need? The Python library seems to only support ^GF indeed, which is not very useful...

@KIKOSoftware Thanks for the insights. Unfortunately, it's not very favorabel for me to do this in Python and do indeed prefer to tackle it on my own in PHP.
Regarding creating a ZPL parser, should I build it by defining specific cases for each ZPL command (For example: making text bold) and then expand from there? Also, you mentioned that ZPL is basic and easy to parse, but also noted that it’s a lot of work. Could you clarify this? Thanks!

It depends on how many commands you need. ZPL II has more than 170 commands, so implementing all of them would obviously be a lot of work.

Yes, of course, for each ZPL command. Have a look at the ZPL manual and Postscript documentation. Read it, understand it. Then use PHP to create a bridge between the two. Stack Overflow isn't the place to explain how to do that.

@KIKOSoftware You don't need to learn PostScript or PDF here. There are libraries for PDF generation.

@Olivier Yes, that's true, PDF has for more libraries than ZPL, and there are some really useful ones out there. One that will do the job, and is simple, is FPDF.

Keep in mind that ZPL is very much pixel-oriented, due to the limitations of label printers, whereas PDF uses a more vector-oriented approach. This gap might be difficult to bridge, and using a (B&W?) image as an intermediary can solve this problem.

By the way, where does the ZPL file come from? Do you generate it?
